# Where does Inkscape 1.x get path settings from?

Tags: environment-variables, path, inkscape

In Inkscape 1.02 on Gentoo Linux I see several duplicate paths in the system settings window (open with CTRL + SHIFT + P)

[image: screenshot with duplicate paths]

I would like to drop obsolete/duplicate paths.
Where does Inkscape get these path information from?

```bash
echo ${PATH}
```

Shows different paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Moini was right: Opening a [ticket on the Inkscape bugtracker](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/4497) was a good and Nathan Lee replied quickly.

I sum up the answer for the other .sx readers, because I expect that several systems need fixes in order to prevent duplicate or wrong paths:

Inkscape uses the paths returned by

`Glib::get_system_data_dirs`

and

`Gtk::IconTheme::get_default()->get_search_path()`.

These can be collected on the command line via

```bash
python3 -c "from gi.repository import GLib; print(GLib.get_system_data_dirs())"
['/usr/local/share', '/usr/share', '/usr/share']

python3 -c "from gi.repository import Gtk; print(Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().get_search_path())"
['/home/myuser/.local/share/icons', '/home/myuser/.icons', 
'/usr/local/share/icons', '/usr/share/icons', '/usr/share/icons', 
'/usr/local/share/pixmaps', '/usr/share/pixmaps', '/usr/share/pixmaps']
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a feature request for Inkscape to make the paths shown in that field unique.
The Inkscape bug tracker is at https://inkscape.org/report .

Comment: Yes, I agree and perhaps I will write a feature request for this. But I am still curious, where the paths come from.

Comment: You'll be able to ask developers directly when you make a report.

Comment: Gave it a try https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/4497